# how to print a section of file between two regular expressions only if a line within the section contains a certain string within it

Tags: shell, printing, sed, awk, multiline

I have a file of events that has multiple multi lined events between `<event>` and `</event>` tags. I want to print out the entire event From `<event>` to `</event>` only if a line within that event contains either the string uniqueId="1279939300.862594_PFM_1_1912320699" or uniqueId="1281686522.353435_PFM_1_988171542". The file has 100000 events in it and each event has between 20 and 35 lines (attributes within the event vary its length). I started off using sed but need a little help beyond:

```
cat xmlEventLog_2010-03-23T* | sed -nr "/<event eventTimestamp/,/<\/event>/"
```

What do I need to do to finish this? Also is sed the best way of doing this given the size of the files?

Thanks in advance

A

I wanted to edit this to update. For certain reasons I want to do this with sed. I tried Denis's solution but it does not seem to work:

```
bash$ grep 1279939300.862594_PFM_1_1912320699 xmlEventLog*
xmlEventLog_2010-03-23T02:41:15_PFM_1_1.xml:    <event eventTimestamp="2010-03-23T02:41:40.861" originalReceivedMessageSize="0" uniqueId="1279939300.862594_PFM_1_1912320699">
bash$ grep 1281686522.353435_PFM_1_988171542 xmlEventLog*
xmlEventLog_2010-03-23T07:47:38_PFM_1_1.xml:    <event eventTimestamp="2010-03-23T08:02:02.299" originalReceivedMessageSize="685" uniqueId="1281686522.353435_PFM_1_988171542">
bash$ time sed -n ':a; /<event>/,/<\/event>/ N; /<event>/,/<\/event>/!b; /<\/event>/ {/uniqueId="1279939300.862594_PFM_1_1912320699"\|uniqueId="1281686522.353435_PFM_1_988171542"/p;d}; ba' xmlEventLog*

real    1m13.134s
user    1m12.463s
sys     0m0.659s
bash$
```

Which obviously returned nothing. So is it possible to do this with sed?

A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
sed -n ':a; /<event>/,/<\/event>/ N; /<event>/,/<\/event>/!b; /<\/event>/ {/uniqueId="1279939300.862594_PFM_1_1912320699"\|uniqueId="1281686522.353435_PFM_1_988171542"/p;d}; ba'
```

Comment: after 15mins of waiting this still hasn't returned an answer. Its probably more suited to smaller files. Thanks though for the multi line sed. This is at a level that I have not used yet so I will study it and learn from it

Comment: dennis a means append a line and is used after a pattern match (from what I could find). Could you explain what it does here as a sole command :a ?

Comment: @amadain: `:` is the label command, `a` is the name of the label, `b` is the branch command. So when `sed` reaches `ba` it branches to label "a" which is `:a` creating a loop. The `b` without a label branches to the end (past the last command) thus exiting the loop. The `d` (delete) command also branches to the end exiting the loop.

Comment: for one of the first times the sed answer is considerably more complicated than the awk answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -vRS="</event>" '/<event>/ && /1279939300.862594_PFM_1_1912320699|1281686522.353435_PFM_1_988171542/{print}' file
```

Comment: This worked brilliant thanks. I am now checking times against the sed one above to see which one is better timewise (as my files are huge). Here are the times for this: real    3m4.890s
user    3m2.273s
sys     0m2.568s

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to embed the unique ids directly into the regular expression, using the `|` character to allow either uniqueid. I did a quick test and the following regular expression seems to find the correct entries:

```
 <event.*?uniqueid=("1279939300\.862594_PFM_1_1912320699"|"1281686522\.353435_PFM_1_988171542").*?</event>
```

Comment: the uniqueId is not necessarily on the same line as the <event> tag

Comment: I have to admit that I'm not familiar with sed, but is there not a toggle to enable multi-line regexes?

Comment: yea. I'm trying Dennis's multi-line sed from above. The awk one worked in around 3 mins